# SagePay v3.0 VSPForm in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, aes, opayo

I am using VSPForm on V3.00 and AES encryption. I have it all set up and working on one site but on another (where everything is identical) I get an error saying Currency field is missing. 
After spending all day trying to sort it with Sage they keep telling me that I am not sending 128 bit encryption and that they cannot decrypt what i am sending. Strange as i am sending the same identical info from another site and that works. I know I am sending 128bit and I can encrypt and decrypt the string sent to them on my own system

For my encrypt I use the following inside a function

```
global $strEncryptionType
      ,$strEncryptionPassword;

$strIV = $strEncryptionPassword;

    //** add PKCS5 padding to the text to be encypted
    $strIn = addPKCS5Padding($strIn);

    //** perform encryption with PHP's MCRYPT module
    $strCrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $strEncryptionPassword, $strIn, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $strIV);

    //** perform hex encoding and return
    return "@" . bin2hex($strCrypt);
```

Does anyone know of any other reason why this error would occur? When checking the post and cart info Currency is definitely set.

Answer (score 0):

The 3045 'Currency' error is usually nothing to do with the currency. It usually indicates that there is something wrong with the encryption - I would check the password is correct, bearing in mind that these are different for live / test.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, for some reason my global vars are not working inside the function even though they are all on the same page
P